# Finding the Order of G, given subgroups

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups

I need help with a practice exam question:

$G$ is a cyclic group that has only 3 subgroups: $e$ (identity), $G$, and $G'$ s.t. |$G'$| = $n$. What is |G| if:

a) $n = 5$

b) $n$ is any prime number $p$.

What I know is that the order of $G'$ divides the order of $G$; so, does that mean |$G$| = $5k$ for some integer $k$? If so, is it the same for $p$, where |$G$|  = $pk$? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The cyclic group of order $ n $ has a unique (cyclic) subgroup of order $ d $ for each $ d $ dividing $ n $. If a cyclic group has $ 3 $ subgroups, this would mean that its order has $ 3 $ positive integer divisors. Which positive integers have exactly $ 3 $ positive integer divisors?

Comment: The only ones I can think of are 4, 6, and 9. But doesn't 5 have to be a factor to one of these numbers?

Comment: $ 6 $ has $ 4 $ positive integer divisors: $ 1, 2, 3, 6 $. Don't focus on specific examples - try to think of how you can read off the number of divisors from the prime factorization of an integer, and work with that.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding some concepts here. The order of a subgroup has to divide the order of the group, right? And if G has only 3 subgroups, then like you said, $G$'s order should only have 3 positive integer divisors. But, for any $k$ (let $5k$ = $m$), $m$ will have at least 4 positive integer divisors: 1, 5, $k$, $m$. I feel like I'm missing a big concept. Where did I go wrong in my logic? Thanks.

Comment: You are correct - but what if your list $ 1, 5, k, m $ does not consist of distinct integers? In other words, what if two integers on that list are actually equal?

Comment: Then that would mean $m$ = would have to be a prime number, right, where $m$ = $k$?

Comment: No, that would not mean that $ m $ would have to be prime number. Look at your list and think about which two elements of your list could be equal to each other. Examine all possible combinations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45722/discussion-between-starfall-and-jack).

Comment: OH I see, $m$ can only have 3 divisors if $k$ = 5. So, the only possible number for $m$ is 25.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. $|G|$ is $5k$ and $pk$ respectively. So you just need to find which value(s) of $k$ ensure that $G$ has exactly 3 subgroups.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but here goes. $G'$(of order 5) is the only proper subgroup of $G$ and assume $|G|= n$. So consider an element $a \in G/G'$. So $a^5 \neq e$. Now, $(a^5)^{n/5} = e$. Denote this element by $b$.Thus $b$ generates another proper subgroup of $G$ distinct from $G'$. Which is not possible. So only case is $n/5=1 \implies n = 5$. Same for any prime $p$. (sorry for the bad notation)

Comment: I did not assume that here. But also $G$ is cyclic. And $ G$ has only one proper subgroup.

Comment: $ G' $ is not a proper subgroup in your example... it has order $ 5 $, and so does your group $ G $.